# How to encrypt a file on remote system and encrypted file should be saved directly in local system

Tags: ssh, openssl

I am using `ssh username@host openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in abc.txt -out abc.txt.enc` for encryption.

How can I encrypt a file in remote system and save the encrypted file directly  in local system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should:

1. Remove the `-out` flag of the `openssl`

   - This will output the encrypted file to `stdout` instead of a file
2. Redirect the output of the `openssl` `stdout` into a file in the local system

e.g.:

```
ssh username@host openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in abc.txt > abc.txt.enc
```

- The abc.txt file should be on the remote server
- The abc.txt.enc file will be written on the local system

Comment: yes it is working then what if   i am using aescrypt "aescrypt -e -p passkey abc.txt" and how to store it directly in local system @Yaron

Comment: @prasanna - If my answer solved your answer (as indicated from your comment) please [accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Comment: @prasanna - If my answer doesn't answer your 2nd question regarding `aescrypt` please open a new question regarding `aescrypt`